# Password Manager - Continuing / Long-Term Things

Tags: c++, passwords

Okay, I know very well how everybody feels about homemade password managers, but I would like help with mine. *Not for actual use*, just for the sake of learning.

I was wondering, in C++ how to have long-term variables. Or really, have anything long-term.

What do I mean by long-term? Something that is saved or continues upon next run of the .exe. In my case, I want where, the first time you run the program it asks you to enter an access password, so next time you launch the program, you will have to type the password chosen when you first launched.

Currently, I just use an if() statement to check if password is equal to my desired password, and if it is, to run. However, that is far from actually effective and isn't very practical.

Something I thought of was to create a text file somewhere containing the access password, and read it, but that kind of defeats the purpose of a password manager.

Comment: Read about *databases*. And it doesn't have to a be something like MySQL or similar, just a simple text file can be a database too.

Comment: For my case, that seems like a little too much. There must be a simple way to affect a program... Practically every program that exists has settings, thing you can change, passwords, etc.

Comment: From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database): "A database is an organized collection of data." Where you store the data doesn't matter, if you store it then it's in a database. Just writing to a file in the filesystem is the simple solution. Using e.g. Redis or SQLite are other solutions.

Comment: @SydZ Any program that "remembers" settings somehow stores them on disk. Database, flat file, Windows registry, the choice is yours (even though I'd strongly advise against the latter, if only for reasons of portability). And once it's stored on disk, it can be read by a user even if you don't want to. To mitigate that, you might want to encrypt your data. A common scheme for passwords is to use a (salted) one-way hash so that it can't be "decrypted", and to compare it against user input you apply the same hash to the input and compare the hashed values.

Answer (score 1):

Every variable in your program is only in memory and lost at exit. You must store it on your disk and later read it from there.

There are many ways to do that directly or indirectly.

A very simple low level way is to use `ofstream` and `ifstream`. E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  using namespace std;

  int counter = 0;

  // try to load counter from file
  {
    ifstream myfile("mycounter.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
      myfile >> counter;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  cout << "current counter: " << counter << endl;

  // save counter to file
  {
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("mycounter.txt");
    myfile << counter << endl;
  }
}
```

You might be more comfortable with the C-functions `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`, `fclose`, etc.

Then, there are databases and there are easy libraries to use such databases. Check out [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/), you can use it from C++.

Answer (score 1):

You could start a database or save/write the data into files.